# is WebKitBlobBuilder available in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I read in many places that Safari has WebKitBlobBuilder implementation (for instance, here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/).

I try the following in a Safari browser I just downloaded both on Mac and Windows, and Safari gives me undefined:

```
alert(window.WebKitBlobBuilder);
```

Here you can see it for yourself (open it from a Safari browser):

http://jsbin.com/anifak/30/edit

Any ideas?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/blobbuilder

Comment: Ok. I checked here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/BlobBuilder it looks like they added the compatibility information for Safari as of August 2011. It says available in nightly build. Does this mean it is coming in the next version?

Comment: I can't say that for sure, but eventually it will I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately my testing says that Safari, even the Nightly Build, doesn't support this, even though many places including the O'Reilly "Programming HTML5 Applications" say otherwise.  I haven't tried it yet, but I noticed someone made a BlobBuilder.js for browsers where the BlobBuilder API isn't supported natively: http://eligrey.com/blog/.

Answer (score 1):

This is nearly a year old, but in case anyone stumbles upon it...

You probably want to use the Blob API now, not the deprecated WebKitBlobBuilder.

See Eric Bidelman's [HTML5 Rocks update](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/Don-t-Build-Blobs-Construct-Them) and his [FileSystem article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Answer (score 0):

I concluded that at the moment Safari does not support this. It is also reported by the link @pimvdb provided http://caniuse.com/blobbuilder.

According to http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/BlobBuilder Safari supports this in its nighly build. So I assume it will be able in the near future.